# Validate RadioButton List Using Javascript and CustomValidator

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a CustomValidator for a RadioButtonList,instead of RequiredFieldValidator, so that I can assign a CSS class using Javascript.The Validation is to check that at least one of the items is selected. The foll. code is not working:

JS:

```
function validateRadioButtonList() {              
            var target = document.getElementById('<%=rbGender.ClientID %>');        
            var radioButtons = target.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var is_valid;
            if (radioButtons[0].checked || radioButtons[1].checked) {
                is_valid = true;
                target.className = "";
            }
            else {
                target.className = "validate";
                is_valid = false;
            }
            args.IsValid = is_valid;
        }
```

ASPX:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
  RepeatLayout="Flow" AutoPostBack="false">
  <asp:ListItem>Male&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Female&nbsp;&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" 
  ControlToValidate="rbGender" ClientValidationFunction="validateRadioButtonList"   
  Text="*" ForeColor="Red"> </asp:CustomValidator>

 <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
  ValidationGroup="vsGroup" />
```

GENERATED HTML:

```
<div class="">
 <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbGender">
 <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbGender_0" type="radio" 
  name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbGender" value="Male  " />
 <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbGender_0">Male  </label>
 <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbGender_1" type="radio" 
  name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbGender" value="Female  " />
 <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_rbGender_1">Female  </label>
 </span>
 <span style="float: right; margin-right: 3%">
 <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CustomValidator3" style="color:Red;
  visibility:hidden;">*  </span>
 </span>
</div>
```

But if I include

```
UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick="validateRadioButtonList()"
```

for the button, it works. I do not want to do so.

Comment: Can you use validation through js.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following:

```
var target = document.getElementById(sender.controltovalidate);
```

Which will find the radio group. Each radio should have it's own ID, because IDs in JS are unique. Therefor you can not select all the radio buttons with just `getElementById` which returns a single object.

Can you show me the HTML which is generated by the controls?

**EDIT**

Like (but if you change your control name this name will be changed aswell, because it is server generated). If you can give it a class it would be better.

```
var target = document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbGender")
```

Comment: sorry, dont know how to do that. Any other way? Also, shouldnt the validation be fired only on postback. Why is it doing with the item's click.

Comment: Hi, I added the html output in the question

Comment: Tried that. The css class now does not apply on selecting a radiobutton. But the validation is not happening on submit's click.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without ASP validators. It can be solved just using the JavaScript. Try this link for a reference:
http://www.felgall.com/javatip2.htm

Comment: I do not want to fire the validation from the submit button and hence the ClientValidationFunction. Is this possible. I have edited my question.Thank you